# Keras Input_shape shape error

Tags: python, input, keras, shapes

When I run the following code:

```
from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras import optimizers
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', input_shape = (4, 4, 512)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=2e-5),
                loss='binary_crossentropy',
                metrics=['acc'])
model.summary()
history = model.fit(train_features, train_labels,
                    epochs=30,
                    batch_size=20,
                    validation_data=(validation_features, validation_labels))
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_40_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (2000, 4, 4, 512)
```

Here is the shape of training and validation data:

```
print(train_features.shape, train_labels.shape, validation_features.shape, validation_labels.shape)
```

Output:

```
(2000, 4, 4, 512) (2000,) (1000, 4, 4, 512) (1000,)
```

Whats happening here? My train and validation shape should be the same as what I just specified. Even when I change to `input_dim = 4*4*512` I still get an error.

Output of `model.summary():`

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_42 (Dense)             (None, 4, 4, 256)         131328    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_19 (Dropout)         (None, 4, 4, 256)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_43 (Dense)             (None, 4, 4, 1)           257       
=================================================================
Total params: 131,585
Trainable params: 131,585
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

My Keras version is 2.1.6.

Comment: What version of Keras are you using? Post the output of this code: `import keras; print(keras.__version__)`.

Comment: Please post the output of `model.summary()` as well.

Comment: `model.summary():
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
===============================================================
dense_42 (Dense)             (None, 4, 4, 256)         131328    


dropout_19 (Dropout)         (None, 4, 4, 256)         0      

dense_43 (Dense)             (None, 4, 4, 1)           257       
Total params: 131,585
Trainable params: 131,585
Non-trainable params: 0`

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this dont know how to make the output look good.

Comment: Keras Version:
*2.1.6*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the model summary the output shape of last layer is `(None, 4, 4, 1)` and since you have one single label for each sample therefore the output shape of last layer should be `(None, 1)` instead. So you must reshape the training data before feeding it to the network or flatten the output of first Dense layer (or maybe add a `Reshape` layer as the first layer).

**Approach 1)** Reshaping the training and validation data:

```
train_features = train_features.reshape((2000, -1))
validation_features = validation_features.reshape((1000, -1))

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', input_dim=train_features.shape[-1]))
# ... the rest is the same
```

**Approach 2)** Adding a `Flatten` layer:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', input_shape = (4, 4, 512)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
# ... the rest is the same
```

I recommend the first approach (unless you have good reasons for choosing the second approach), <strike>since according to the [Dense layer documentation](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dense) input of this layer with rank greater than 2 (i.e. 3D, 4D, etc.) is flattened before applying dot product. And considering that you apply another flatten operation in the second approach, this may be less efficient than feeding it with a 2D tensor directly (though, I have not confirmed this myself, it is just a wild guess!).</strike> [It seems that the documentation is wrong](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10736#issuecomment-406589140) and the input of Dense layer is not flattened, rather it is applied on the last axis.

---

As a side note: the error you got is a bit strange. I didn't get that when running your code on my machine. Instead, I got an error complaining about the output shape of the last layer being not compatible with the labels shape (which I addressed above).

Comment: Thank you! But why would added a flatten layer after first layer help?

Comment: Plus, why would convert a (2000,4,4,512) feature to (2000,-1) be a good idea?

Comment: @ZhangXianhan Because you want to predict one value (i.e. label) for the each sample. Therefore the input shape of last Dense layer should be in the form `(?, dim)` in order for it to predict one value. Otherwise it would output a tensor of shape `(4,4,1)` for a training sample (as you can see in the model summary). This is not what you are looking for. You want it to output only one value (i.e. shape `(1,)`). Further, I am reshaping training data from `(2000,4,4,512)` to `(2000, 4x4x512)` (that `-1` tells numpy to find the shape automatically). That way we don't need to use Flatten at all.

Comment: Got you, in order to use the last sigmoid function, the input cant have multiple dimensions. Thank you for the kind help!

Comment: @ZhangXianhan No, it is not related to sigmoid function (it can be applied on any tensor by computing it element-wise). It is related to the shape of labels. You have labels of shape `(2000, 1)` so the output of last layer should be also of shape `(2000, 1)` and not `(2000, 4,4,1)` (ignore those 2000; actually you should replace it with the batch size, I just used it for demonstrations). In other words if your labels had a shape of `(2000, 4,4,1)` then everything would be solved and your initial network would work without problems.

Comment: I am confused here, I already specified `model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))`, why would the output be (?,4,4,1) instead of (?,1).

Comment: Alright, i I think model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) only specified the last dimension, it wont change the dim of previous layer.

Comment: @ZhangXianhan Yes, right. That's only the last dimension. If you read Dense layer documentation you will see that the input shape of Dense layer is `(batch_size, ..., input_dim)` and the output shape is `(batch_size, ..., units)` where `units` refers to the number of units you specify for the layer.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Before use Dense(), you should call Flatten().
the error is obvious, Dense net expect 2 dim while you fitted it with 4 dim.

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(Flattern(input_shape = (4, 4, 512)))
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
```